# C# multiple joins and not existing in another table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

The part of the code I am working on is a file uploader. I select a `cid` and a `clientid` and then I upload a file of a selected category. After that I can choose a `site` from a dropdown to select which `site` this file belongs to. I have another grid which informs the user of which `sites` don't have the required file categories yet.

I have 4 tables:
`Categories(id) - TemplateCs(cid, CatId, Required, Clientid) - Sites(cid,SiteId,FullName) - Files(SiteId, CatId)`

What I want to achieve is: Given a specific `cid` and a `Clientid` I want to get all the `Sites` that dont have files uploaded of the required `Categories`

Here is what I have tried so far for `cid11` and Categories.id = id34:

```
var sites = (from mc in dc.Categories
                        join mat in dc.TemplateCs on mc.Id equals mat.Catid
                        join st in dc.Sites on mat.cid equals st.Cid
                         where ((!dc.Files.Any(x => x.SiteId == st.Siteid && x.CatId == Convert.ToInt32(id))) && mat.Required == true && mat.Clientid == int.Parse(clientid.First().ToString()) && mat.cid == cid11 && mc.Id == id34) 
                        select new CustomObject() { Siteid = st.Siteid, Site = st.FullName });
```

But using this code every time I upload a file and select a site the selected category disappears from the `Missing` grid. Even that there are some sites that dont have a file from the selected category.

**EDIT**
Here is a snapshot of the two grids (as you can see in the missing files grid the user expands one category and gets the sites that don't have files of the required categories. In the snapshot you can see also that the missing grid should contain the "Trial Management Plan" category for `test site 2`, but it doesnt):
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a good start before asking long questions.

Comment: @jarlh thank you. tried to make it shorter

Answer (score 0):

Updated query to return sites for a specific category:

```
var sites = (from mc in dc.Categories
             join mat in dc.TemplateCs on mc.Id equals mat.Catid
             join st in dc.Sites on mat.cid equals st.Cid
             where (!dc.Files.Any(f => f.SiteId == st.Siteid && f.CatId == mat.Catid) && mat.Required == true && mat.Clientid == int.Parse(clientid.First().ToString()) && mat.cid == cid11 && mc.Id == id34)
             select new CustomObject() { Siteid = st.Siteid, Site = st.FullName });
```

PS I am surprised you don't want to include the category(s) of missing file(s) in the Missing grid.

Comment: Please check my edited post, it's explaining why I am restricting the required categories to id34. Its a Row Expander, user clicks on a category and should get the list of sites that dont have files of the required categories

Comment: I updated my query to return sites missing a specific category.